# What is this plant with the prune tree?

Tags: tree-care

I have planted a prune tree last year and today when I looked at it, I saw it was made of 2 kinds of plants. I am not even sure which one is which.

So my questions are:

What are these plants?
Should I remove them?

[image: Prune tree plants]

Comment: The one that is the most vigorous is the weed. The prune tree has the red stems and should have lenticels or tiny bumps on the stems.

Comment: @kevinsky do all plums have lenticals? I know cherries do, but I don't recall seeing them on my plums when I had such. I don't currently have any stone fruit trees to look at other than flowering cherries in the neighbors yard. :-/

Comment: @Escoce you are right, plum trees do not have lenticels, only cherry trees. see http://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/british-columbia/8-ways-to-tell-a-cherry-blossom-from-a-plum-blossom-1.2595629

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what the weed is, but you should definitely remove it as it is not allowing the prune tree to get the sunlight it needs, and the weed is competing with the prune tree for water and nutrients in the soil.  Be sure to remove the weed carefully so as not to damage the roots of your prune tree.

Answer (score 1):

Your second plant looks like a variety of mint. Here is a link with various types of mint: http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/edible/herbs/mint/mint-plant-varieties.htm

Pinching off a leaf and smelling it should verify this. Mint roots can strangle out all other small root plants near it. Be sure to clear as much of the mint roots as possible and pluck any new growth you find. Remove all the root bits you can as mint may regrow from a small bit of root.
.